# How to clean JSON data to export only the necessary columns to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a json file(pulled using json request) :

```
{
    "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
        "1. From_Currency Code": "AUD",
        "2. From_Currency Name": "Australian Dollar",
        "3. To_Currency Code": "USD",
        "4. To_Currency Name": "United States Dollar",
        "5. Exchange Rate": "0.64871880",
        "6. Last Refreshed": "2020-05-13 10:55:40",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC",
        "8. Bid Price": "0.64871460",
        "9. Ask Price": "0.64855470"
    }
}
```

I need to export data from only these columns:

```
 1.From_Currency Code,3. To_Currency Code,5. Exchange Rate,6. Last Refreshed
```

The dataframe should look something like this :

```
From      To        ExchangeRate        LastRefeshed
AUD      USD        0.64871880          020-05-13 10:55:40
```

I tried doing this :

```
dfs = {k:pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(x)) for k, x in df.pop('Co2').items()}
```

But i dont know what arguments to give in df.pop

Comment: I may be stupid, but I could not guess what was the input dataframe `df`...

Comment: I am just pushing the JSON to a dataframe

Comment: Could you say exactly how you do it?

Comment: data = requests.get(url)
    content = data.json()   
    resp = json.dumps(content)
    response_df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(resp))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(s).T; 

df = df[[ '1. From_Currency Code','3. To_Currency Code',
         '5. Exchange Rate','6. Last Refreshed']]
```

Comment: Could you explain what  pd.DataFrame(s).T means. And what is s here ?

Comment: `s` is your JSON as a dictionary, e.g. `s = ast.literal_eval(x)`

Comment: Transpose is giving me all the data value right next to the column name , but i want data part below the column name

Comment: Chain `pd.DataFrame().T.reset_index()`?